# Usage i18n-n functional component in NuxtJS

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

How can I use [i18n-n functional component](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/api/#i18n-n-functional-component) in Nuxt?
[Vue i18n Guide](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/number.html#custom-formatting) says I can use it like this:

```html
<i18n-n :value="1234" :format="{ key: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }">
  <span v-slot:currency="slotProps" styles="color: green">{{ slotProps.currency }}</span>
  <span v-slot:integer="slotProps" styles="font-weight: bold">{{ slotProps.integer }}</span>
  <span v-slot:group="slotProps" styles="font-weight: bold">{{ slotProps.group }}</span>
  <span v-slot:fraction="slotProps" styles="font-size: small">{{ slotProps.fraction }}</span>
</i18n-n>
```

But Nuxt with [i18n module](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/) doesn't know anything about `<i18n-n></i18n-n>` component and throws an error

Comment: This one is available since `v8.10+` of `vue-i18n`. Could you go to your `yarn.lock` and check the version of this package there? Your `nuxt-i18n` is probably not high enough. Updating this one, will probably bump `vue-i18n` and allow for this new feature. Also, what is the error?

Comment: @kissu I use last version of [Nuxt i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-i18n) - 6.27.3. I don't know which version of the Vue i18n this modul based on.
Error is `v-slot can only be used on components or <template>`

Comment: There is an open issue available here: https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/1127#issue-815262350 You could maybe give your setup there and therefore bump the issue.

Comment: @kissu I asked there and some guy offers the smart idea: `<i18n-n :value="100" format="currency"><template #integer="slotProps"><span>{{ slotProps.integer }}</span></template></i18n-n>`. This approach doesn't throws an error, but renders only empty wrapper tag `<div></div>`. Do you have any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: The guy is actually a Nuxt.js ambassador in charge of the nuxt module for i18n. :)

Answer (score 2):

### Solved!

The correct code:

```html
<i18n-n :value="1234" :format="{ key: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }">
  <template v-slot:currency="slotProps">
    <span styles="color: green">{{ slotProps.currency }}</span>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:integer="slotProps">
    <span styles="font-weight: bold">{{ slotProps.integer }}</span>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:group="slotProps">
    <span styles="font-weight: bold">{{ slotProps.group }}</span>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:fraction="slotProps">
    <span styles="font-size: small">{{ slotProps.fraction }}</span>
  </template>
</i18n-n>
```

Also you need to set up `numberFormat` [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55443835/nuxt-i18n-number-localization/59597971#59597971)

**Thanks:**

[@kissu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8816585/kissu) for finding [actual issue](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/1127)

[@rchl](https://github.com/rchl) for [working approach](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/1127#issuecomment-884319610)

[@ashkanz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7338291/ashkan) for [correctly set up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55443835/nuxt-i18n-number-localization/59597971#59597971) `numberFormats`

Answer (score 1):

This Github issue solved OP's issue: https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/1127

It was essentially some poor documentation and some configuration required.