# nuxt-i18n : date localization doesn't work for me

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt-i18n

I am trying to localize DateTime with Nuxt/i18n,
but it doesn't work!

This is what I have in the config of Nuxt/i18n in nuxt config:

```json
  {
        seo: true,
        locales: [
          {
            code: 'en',
            iso: 'en-US',
            file: 'en.js',
            dir: 'ltr',
            name: 'English',
            id: 2,
          }
       
        ],

        lazy: true,
        langDir: 'locales/',
       
        defaultLocale: 'en',
        strategy: 'prefix_except_default',
        dateTimeFormats: {
          'en-US': {
            short: {
              year: 'numeric',
              month: 'long',
              day: 'numeric',
              weekday: 'short',
            },
            long: {
              year: 'numeric',
              month: 'short',
              day: 'numeric',
              weekday: 'short',
              hour: 'numeric',
              minute: 'numeric',
            },
          
          },
        },
      },
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: @JasonLandbridge , because my code is long and Stack doesn't let me post , i forced to add "how can i fix this " to longer text content

Comment: @JasonLandbridge , i use ```  <p>{{ $d(new Date(), 'short') }}</p> ``` for localization But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use the vueI18n option in the i18n part of your nuxt.config.js

```
modules: [
['nuxt-i18n', {
   locales: [
     {
       code: 'en',
       iso: 'en-US',
       file: 'en-US.js'
     }
   ],
   lazy: true,
   langDir: 'lang/',
   defaultLocale: 'en',
   vueI18n: {
     dateTimeFormats: {
       en: {
         short: {
           year: 'numeric',
           month: 'short',
           day: 'numeric',
         },
       }
     },
     numberFormats: {
       en: {
         currency: {
            style: 'currency', 
             currency: 'USD'
            }
       }
     }
   }
 }
],
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55443835/nuxt-i18n-number-localization) post